# a weird error when trying to write to HDFS using CDH-5.2.0

Tags: hdfs, apache-spark, cloudera

i am trying to write to a cluster of five spark nodes, we are using CDH-5.2.0, just upgraded from a previous version and the problems arrived. Now i am not able to write data to the cluster.

This are dependencies from pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-cdh5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-cdh5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this is the actual code that i use to write to HDFS:

```
public class MyHadoopUtils {

final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyHadoopUtils.class);
private static FileSystem fs;
static{
    Configuration myConf = new Configuration();     
    myConf.set("fs.defaultFS", MyWatchService.getDEFAULTFS());      
    myConf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    myConf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
    try {
        fs = FileSystem.get(myConf);

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("ATTENTION! an error occurred when trying to instantiate a hadoop file system handler!. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("ATTENTION! an error occurred when trying to instantiate a hadoop file system handler!. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("ATTENTION! an error occurred when trying to instantiate a hadoop file system handler!. " + th.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

public static boolean saveWithinHDFS(String path,StringBuffer sb) throws IOException{
    boolean isOk=false;
    Path pt = new Path(path);
    try {
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(pt, true)));
        br.write(sb.toString());
        br.close();
        isOk=true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        LOGGER.info("ATTENTION! it is been imposible to save a file within HDFS!. path: " + path);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

and this is the stackstrace:

```
[WARN][FeedAdapter][2014-12-15 09:15:45] NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$GetServerDefaultsRequestProto overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2690)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2700)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(ProxyGenerator.java:426)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(ProxyGenerator.java:323)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:672)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:592)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:244)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:455)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getProxy(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at com.tekcomms.c2d.utils.MyHadoopUtils.<clinit>(MyHadoopUtils.java:27)
```

The warning is not bothering me because i know that is provoked by a 32 bit compiled version of a certain library when the machine is x64, i guess that cloudera guys will provide us a 64 bit version, but this error is really weird.

Please help

UPDATE

mvn dependency:tree looks like this:

```
http://pastebin.com/s8Ti0HG3
```

To me looks fine, maybe some jar of this list is provided ad hoc by cloudera?

Comment: The deps look fine. I am not sure why you think it has something to do with Cloudera. The jars are not tricky. You almost surely have other Hadoop versions on your classpath at *runtime*.

Comment: Hi @SeanOwen, that is exactly what i think, the deps look fine, and no classpath variable is declared, i invoke the jar using the next command: java -jar target/myjar mypropertiesfile.properties, so i do not know if i have another hadoop version. I am using this kernel,  2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 and jdk is java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.1.2.el6_5-x86_64 u65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode). Nothing relevant declared on .bash_profile or .bashrc

Comment: well i fix the problem, but i do not know why, because it started to work perfectly when i changed the position within pom.xml of a third party dependency...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with 64 bits, or CDH. The error suggests you have included two different incompatible versions of Hadoop in your app. Maybe one of your dependencies is bringing in other versions or you have added another accidentally at runtime

Comment: Bang on @Sean ... I resolved the issue by removing the `<dependency>` block for `hadoop-common` and it selected the correct version from the hadoop runtime